# How to save a formula as a string in VBA

Tags: vba

I've got the following code

```
Sub reset_formulas()

uptime_formula = "=IFS(AND(C25="Deployed",C26="Returned"), B26-B25, AND(C25="Returned",C26="Deployed"), 0, AND(C25="Deployed",C26="Deployed"),TODAY()-B25, AND(C25="Returned",C26="Returned"), 0, AND(C25="Deployed",C26=""), TODAY()-B25, AND(C25="Returned",C26=""), 0)"

End Sub
```

And I keep getting an error message of "Syntax Error" which I'm guessing is due to the " " characters around the words "Deployed" and "Returned".

Is there an easy way to save a formula as a string in Excel?

Comment: You will need to double-up any of the quotes between the opening and closing quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formulas quickly become a mess. In code, you can break it up in (sub)lines, like this example:

```vb
' Build a cell formula like:
'
'   =SUMPRODUCT(ROUND(Tabel_1234[ColumnName1]*Tabel_1234[ColumnName2]*Tabel_1234[ColumnName3],2))
'
Public Function BuildSumproductResource( _
    ByRef Table As ListObject, _
    ByVal ColumnIndex1, _
    ByVal ColumnIndex2, _
    ByVal ColumnIndex3) _
    As String

    Const Sum       As String = "=SUMPRODUCT(ROUND("
    
    Dim Formula     As String
    
    Formula = Sum & _
        Table.Name & _
        "[" & Table.ListColumns(ColumnIndex1).Name & "]*" & _
        Table.Name & _
        "[" & Table.ListColumns(ColumnIndex2).Name & "]*" & _
        Table.Name & _
        "[" & Table.ListColumns(ColumnIndex3).Name & "]," & _
        "2))"

    BuildSumproductResource = Formula

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the formula from a specified cell directly this might help.

```
Sub reset_formulas()

    Dim uptime_formula As String: uptime_formula = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Formula)
    Debug.Print uptime_formula

End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is that the formula won't be stored in a cell so I need a way to save it in a variable. I am trying to replace the "" with Chr(34) but that's quite confusing because the formula is so long so I was expecting there was another way to do this

Comment: where are you getting these formulas from

Comment: Basically it is currently on a cell, but the data will change by the moment that I decide to run my macro so I wanted to save the formula somehow so I can have it in there in the future when I decide to get my data to its original format.

Comment: so if you use the code I provided you could:

1. Save the cells formula to a string variable 
2. Run your other macro
3. place the formula back onto the cell

Unless im missing something?